# GA - Days since last session - when there are multiple sessions in a time frame

Tags: google, analytics

What about if the time frame I am looking at is 7 days and some users return more than once?

If a user visits monday, than returns wednesday, and then again thursday, that would count 1, 2 or 3 days?

Answer (score 1):

The "?" next to the column "Days since last session" states "The number of days from the close of one session to the opening of another".  Based on that and using your example, the answer would be one day since the users last session.  You can also look at https://www.nngroup.com/articles/frequency-recency/

Answer (score 1):

As the 'days since last session' is supposed to be reported in sessions, not users, I think the user in your example is counted two times. So there's one session with 'days since last session' of 2, and one session with 'days since last session' of 1.